# Node JS Cannot find module 'node-properties-parser' Error while running as normal user in Amazon Linux

Tags: javascript, node.js, linux, node-modules, amazon-linux

I have installed `node-properties-parser` globally by running `npm install -g node-properties-parser` as normal user(vaisakh). Then i ran my `test.js` file with the command `node test.js` now it's throwing the error

```
Error: Cannot find module 'node-properties-parser'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:476:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:424:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:504:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/data02/bamboo/test.js:3:12)
    at Module._compile (module.js:577:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:586:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:494:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:453:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:445:3)
```

I ran the above `npm install -g node-properties-parser` as root user and run the `node test.js` here it's working fine. But why it's throwing the error while running as normal user?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks. Finally i found the answer, it's working when in run `sudo npm install node-properties-parser` without the `-g` option. But still i don't know why the `-g` option is not woking, in the docs it's given as `install globally`.

Comment: never use 'sudo' while doing npm i